# Modify third level of a multidimensional array by reference using nested loops

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, reference

I want to change all of the 0 values to a random number between 1 and 6 in the following input array.

```
$_SESSION['diceRoll'] = [
    ["save_1" => ["pos1" => 0, "pos2" => 2, "pos3" => 0, "pos4" => 0, "pos5" => 3, "pos6" => 0]],
    ["save_2" => ["pos1" => 0, "pos2" => 6, "pos3" => 0, "pos4" => 5, "pos5" => 1, "pos6" => 0]],
    ["save_3" => ["pos1" => 2, "pos2" => 0, "pos3" => 5, "pos4" => 0, "pos5" => 2, "pos6" => 2]],
    ["save_4" => ["pos1" => 0, "pos2" => 6, "pos3" => 6, "pos4" => 5, "pos5" => 5, "pos6" => 0]],
    ["save_5" => ["pos1" => 2, "pos2" => 0, "pos3" => 4, "pos4" => 4, "pos5" => 0, "pos6" => 0]],
    ["save_6" => ["pos1" => 3, "pos2" => 0, "pos3" => 4, "pos4" => 0, "pos5" => 5, "pos6" => 5]]
];
```

Any values that are already non-zero should remain unchanged.

I tried modifying the array by reference with the following code, but there seems to be no effect to the array.

```
function foo(&$var) {
  foreach ($var as $key) {
    foreach ($var as $key) {
      foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
        $value = mt_rand(1,6);
      }
    }
  }
}
unset($var); // break the reference

foo($_SESSION['diceRoll']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly modify by reference in each nested loop.  Notice the ~&`prepended to each value variable of each`foreach()` loop.

```
function changeZeroes(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as &$subarray) {
        foreach ($subarray as &$dice) {
            $dice = array_map(function($value) {
                return $value == 0 ? mt_rand(1, 6) : $value;
            }, $dice);
        }
    }
}

changeZeroes($_SESSION['diceRoll']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the 3 levels of nesting and return the desired payload, use `array_map()` calls to read the lowest associative elements and then only overwrite a given value with a random value if it is zero ("falsey") with the Elvis operator.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DVoU4))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($set) => array_map(
            fn($row) => array_map(
                fn($v) => $v ?: rand(1,6),
                $row
            ),
            $set
        ),
        $_SESSION['diceRoll']
    )
);
```

---

If you want to modify by reference, then use `&` in all loop signatures. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LCmHH))

```
function updateMissingDiceRolls(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as &$set) {
        foreach ($set as &$row) {
            foreach ($row as &$val) {
                $val = $val ?: mt_rand(1, 6);
            }
        }
    }
}
updateMissingDiceRolls($_SESSION['diceRoll']);
var_export($_SESSION['diceRoll']);
```

---

A more concise/direct way to affect the leaf nodes of your 3-level array would be to use `array_walk_recursive()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/T16dl)) ([or without the custom function](https://3v4l.org/291vb))

```
function updateMissingDiceRolls(&$array) {
    array_walk_recursive($array, fn(&$v) => $v = $v ?: mt_rand(1, 6));
}
updateMissingDiceRolls($_SESSION['diceRoll']);
var_export($_SESSION['diceRoll']);
```